# Matlab: Repmat and orthogonal vectors

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, orthogonal

I have three vectors which are orthogonal

```
   b_vect = [1 2]
   L_vect = [10 20 30]
   f_vect = [100 200 300]
```

and I would like to do element-for element-operations. I use repmat to duplicate the vectors along the other dimensions so 3D arrays are obtained.

```
   b_arr = repmat(b_vect , [length(f_vect), length(L_vect), 1])   % Wrong?!
   L_arr = repmat(L_vect , [length(f_vect), 1, length(b_vect)])   % Good!
   f_arr = repmat(f_vect', [1, length(L_vect), length(b_vect)])  % Good!
```

This however goes wrong because of the orientation of `b_vect`. For `f_arr` it was possible to take the rotated vector `f_vect'$`, but how should this be done in the case of `b_vect`?

```
   size(b_arr)
   size(L_arr)
   size(f_arr)
```

The element-for-element product would for instance then be

```
   product = b_arr.*L_arr.*f_arr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
b_vect = reshape([1 2],[1 1 numel(b_vect)]);
```

Comment: Indeed, what I need is basically:
b_vect_shaped = reshape(b_vect, [1 1 length(b_vect)]) and use that one in b_arr